# Merge tag [parse-cloud] into [cloud-code]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both [parse-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-cloud) and [cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-code) are being used for the same purpose, and hence it makes sense to merge them. [cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-code) should remain as it is more descriptive and has more questions, [parse-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-cloud) makes little sense now as the hosted Parse.com cloud no longer exists.

I'm not entirely sure how this works but ideally I think all questions tagged with [parse-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-cloud) should instead be tagged with [cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-code) and then the [parse-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-cloud) tag should be removed.

Comment: Someone with a score >= 5 on the `cloud-code` tag should suggest `parse-cloud` as a synonym to trigger the process. @TomFox if you have such a score you can do that as well, I can't unfortunately, but I have the privilege to vote on the synonym suggestion. You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

Comment: @Manuel Annoyingly I don't have enough score but good to know that's how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My concern with the tag [cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-code) was that the tag name was quite generic and users could be utilizing it for any "code" that runs on "cloud". I went through the set of [just 15 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcloud-code%5D+-%5Bparse-platform%5D+-%22parse%22++-%22parse.com%22+-%5Bparse-server%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0) that didn't have parse in their body, or parse related tags, and there were a few questions about the Google's [Cloud Code](https://cloud.google.com/code/), for which I created the [google-cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-code) tag.

Now that the [cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-code) tag was clean. I added [parse-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-cloud) as a synonym for [cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-code), that is:

[parse-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-cloud) (× 67) → [cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-code) (× 1024)

Given that there are more than a thousand posts about Parse Cloud Code, and around 5 for Google's Cloud Code, I have left the [cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-code) as is for now. If there is an influx of Google's Cloud Code questions containing [cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-code) tag instead, then we would need to rename [cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-code) into something more descriptive.

That said, if you all are fine with renaming the [cloud-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-code) tag, right now, feel free to post a suggestion as a comment on this post, and I'll try to rename the tag.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I'm happy with cloud-code for now - @Manuel how about you?

Comment: I think it made sense back then. Looking at it now with the new overview for all [Parse Platform related tags on SE sites](https://community.parseplatform.org/t/parse-related-stackexchange-tags), I think we need a tag `parse-cloud-code` analogous to `google-cloud-code`. Then we should retag all `cloud-code` questions with `parse-cloud-code` and make `parse-cloud` a synonym of `parse-cloud-code`. @BhargavRao what do you think?

Comment: Yep, we can rename [cloud-code] to [parse-cloud-code]. That is a trivial change anyway.

Comment: Great! @TomFox already agreed to this change in the link above, so we much appreciate if you could rename the tag and add parse-cloud as a synonym.

Comment: Done. Now off to bed.